# Remove of duplicate strings from very big text file

Tags: c#, string, duplicates

I have to remove duplicate strings from extremely big text file (100 Gb+)

Since in memory duplicate removing is hopeless due to size of data, I have tried bloomfilter but of no use beyond something like 50 millions strings ..

total strings are like 1 trillion+

I want to know what are the ways to solve this problem..

My initial attempt is, dividing the file in to number of sub files , sort each file and then merge all files together...

If you have better solution than this please let me know,

Thanks..

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is a "string"?

Comment: string length varies from 10 to 128 characters

Comment: You're on the right track; a disk based merge sort would do it for you. After that it's just a single pass through the file.

Comment: There's probably some fancy algorithm that all the CS students learn first year, but if I had to not think about it for very long, I might say think of something like implementing a disk based hashset. Pick a value for the number of buckets that make sense, call it *n*. Create n files. Get the hash code of each string, and take that value % n (call the result *m*) to see what bucket it belongs to. Then check the file corresponding to m to see if the string exists within it. If not, add it. Move to the next string. Once this process is done, you can then merge the files.

Comment: Basic idea is forget the sort. Just create a large number of buckets, the larger the better, then scan the buckets.

Comment: @Anthony - so you're suggesting 1 trillion+ file scans (required to check for the existence of the string in a bucket)? Ouch.

Comment: @Brian, I'm suggesting a large number of files for a minimum number of lookups. Again, it's basically a hashset algorithm. You are going to process 1 trillion strings, you do not avoid that. But the idea is that the more buckets you have, the less strings you must look at, the quicker you find the duplicate. For example, if I have 100 strings in 20 buckets, average of 5 per bucket, then for the 101st string, I only need to find the right bucket (1 step) and then look at 5 strings. Does that make sense? Add more buckets, you look at even less.

Comment: Right ... but you're still doing a complete file scan for every key you hash. Regardless of your bucket size that's 1 trillion + file open/read/(write)/close operations. A disk based merge sort is going to be ... much more efficient. The disk seek latency alone would kill you and since he said it's a 100G file you can kiss any help from the disk cache goodbye.

Comment: I'm neither a hardware person nor do I have a CS background. Like I said, I fully expect anybody with actual knowledge of either to scoff at my suggestion. Fortunately, I don't have to remove duplicate strings from 100GB files in my day job.

Comment: @BrianRoach: you don't have to do it once per string. You can imitate the way an external sort happens. For ex. if you wish to do it 100 MB of memory, you'd load 50 MB data at once and split it into in-memory buckets. As an when a bucket is bigger than 10 MB you drop it to a file. And iterate. Of course this all could get better with some optimizations

Comment: (a) what is the goal? (b) you completely fail to mention what the 'strings' look like. E.g. it would make an extremely big difference if all strings were of the same length, and whether or not they are delimited.

Comment: @sehe strings are urls without urlscheme (http://, ftp:// etc), file format is one url per line.

Comment: @Shivraj - Can you post your Bloom filter parameters (or implementation) and the percentage of duplicates you expect?

Comment: @Shivraj - Are you looking to do this once or many times? That is a significant thing to specify too.

Comment: I've missed something here. How do you get to 1 trillion (10^12) strings in a file of the order 10^11 bytes?

Comment: Other curiosity, how often are duplicates to be found? Is it every often, or just a few odd cases, or truly unknown? I had a smaller case (~10 Go files) where it turned out most identical messages were bunched together, mostly pre-sorted. Finding the unique ones was easy, just look at the next line, see if it's the same. At the end, the few rare repetitions didn't matter too much.

Comment: @MPelletier - Duplicates are finding randomly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key concept you are looking for here is [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).  You should be able to merge sort the whole file using the techniques described in that article and then run through it sequentially to remove duplicates.

If the article is not clear enough have a look at the referenced implementations such as [this one](http://cis.stvincent.edu/html/tutorials/swd/extsort/extsort.html).

Comment: Yep. CS basics and Wikipedia in help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make second file, which contains records, each record is 64-bit CRC plus offset of the string and file should be indexed for fast search. 
Something like this:

```
ReadFromSourceAndSort()
{
   offset=0;
   while(!EOF)
   {
      string = ReadFromFile();
      crc64 = crc64(string);
      if(lookUpInCache(crc64))
      {
         skip;
      } else {
         WriteToCacheFile(crc64, offset);
         WriteToOutput(string);
      }
   }
}
```

How to make good cachefile? It should be sorted by CRC64 to search fast. So you shuold to make structure of this file like binary searching tree, but with fast adding of new items without moving existing in the file. To improve speed you need to use [Memory Mapped Files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Possible answer:

```
memory = ReserveMemory(100 Mb);
mapfile= MapMemoryToFile(memory, "\\temp\\map.tmp"); (File can be bigger, Mapping is just window)
currentWindowNumber = 0;

while(!EndOfFile)
{
  ReadFromSourceAndSort(); But only for first 100 Mb in memory
  currentWindowNumber++;
  MoveMapping(currentWindowNumber)
}
```

And Function To lookup; Shuld not use mapping (because each window switching saves 100 Mb to HDD and loads 100 Mb of the next window). Just seeks in 100Mb Trees of CRC64 and if CRC64 found -> string is already stored

Comment: Thanks for the idea of Binary Search tree. Also I am verifying different approaches, 1) Disk based Bloom filter (which will take 1 byte/string) 2) Disk based Hashset/SortedSet based on .NET Hashset/SortedSet class 3) External Sorting 4) Databases (sqlite /sql server etc)